# cannot click the button when using input tag as a button type

Tags: html, css

I used the submit button as an input type . it can't be clicked but when i use it as a button tag it works fine

how can i fix this ?

**ignore** i'm trying to add more details but the forum don't accept my post and it keep saying "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." that's why i'm trying to make my post bigger.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"> 
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>CONTACT US</h1>
    <div>
        
<form method="GET" action="index.php">
    <label for="name">name</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter your name" name="name">
    <br>
    <label for="email">email</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="enter your email" name="email">
    <br>
    <label for="day of birth">date of birth</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="birth">
    <br>
    <label for="password">password</label>
    <br>
    <input type="password" placeholder="enter your password" name="pass">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>
</div>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo $_POST['email'];
    echo $_POST['name'];
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

i know it might be not useful but this is the stylesheet too

```
body{
    background: #f5f5f5;


}
h1{
    text-align: center;
    color: grey;
}
div{
    background: white;
    max-width: 500px;
    border: dotted grey 1px;
    float: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-bottom:10%;
    
}
label{
    display:block;
    margin:1px;
    margin-right:125px;
    margin-left:125px;
    color: grey;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;


}

input{
    border: 1px grey dotted;
    display:block;
    height:30px;
    margin:1px;
    margin-left:125px;
    margin-right:125px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 250px;
    outline:none;
    text-align: center;
}



input.button{

    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: grey 1px solid;
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: darkgrey;
    margin:20px;
    margin-right:175px;
    margin-left:175px;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying just the `type` doesn't make it **clickable**. For tags other than those ***default clickables***, you have to specify the `click` event for them to listen to a click.

```js
document.querySelector('input').onclick = ()=> alert('clicked')
```

```html
<input class="button" type="button" value="submit" name="submit">
```

**OR** directly specify the `onclick` in the tag itself-

```html
<input class="button" type="button" value="submit" name="submit"
onclick='alert("clicked")'>
```

**However using event in HTML is less preferable, so try to avoid it.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `type="submit"` in the input instead of `type="button"`, and it will automatically call the form action and submit it.

```html
<form method="GET" action="index.php">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>
```